# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$concat'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using:

db.version()

3.2.3

version()

3.2.0-17-gde480c0

```js
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    { $concat: [ "$element", " - ", "$Eventtype" ] }
])
```

gives me the following error:

```
"assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$concat'",
    "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using $concat as a pipeline stage in the aggregation pipeline.

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for a list of the stages.

$concat is used as a string modifier to concatenate the results.

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#examples) for examples.

They tend to use $concat in a $project pipeline stage in the examples to combine two values of a document into one.

For instance:

```
{ $project: { itemDescription: { $concat: [ "$item", " - ", "$description" ] } } }
```

in your case it might look something like...

```
{ $project: { event: { $concat: [ "$element", " - ", "$Eventtype" ] } } }
```

Comment: Far from it.  Aggregation is in my opinion the most complex part of MongoDB.  There's a lot to it, and it's very unforgiving with syntactical errors.  Knowing where to look and what to look for is most of the battle.  

(I didn't know about the $concat operator until I looked at your question)